# How to write this list to a column using setValues() on Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, setvalue

I've been trying to get this list to show on a column on Google Sheets, but it only writes the first value (27):
[image]

If I use setValues(), then it throws me an error.

Appreciate your help - as usual!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var idList = uniqueIDs1.filter ( x => !uniqueIDs2.includes (x) ).map ( x =>[x] )
```

and, at te end of the snippet you posted,  use setValues(idList)

Comment: Right on! Thank you!